# Get the current connected username in socket.io and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Hi Guys got a question how can i get all the user from socket `AddUsers` and transfer it  socket `get winners` ? I'm trying to call it directly to the function but it doenst show up..do i need to save it to the cookies?

```
var usernames = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){



     socket.on('addUsers', function (data) {

     var users   = {
         data : data.box,
         socket_id : socket.id
     }

      socket.username = data.username;
          usernames.push({username : data.username, itemid : data.itemid,  box : data.box,socket_id : socket.id});

         socket.emit('displayUsers', {users: usernames});
     });


     socket.on('get winners', function (data) {
     socket.emit('display winners', {data: usernames});

     });




});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare another variable to keep it like:

```
var usernames = [];
var sockets = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    sockets[socket.id] = socket;
    socket.on('addUsers', function (data) {
        ...
    }
}
```

That's it. When you want to use it, just type "sockets[yourSocketId].emit()"